# How to schedule more than 1 but unknown number of Jobs in Cron Quartz?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I can schedule multiple jobs when I know exactly when their number is known but now I Job requests coming and and I don't know how to schedule them.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you run into?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by building a layer on top of scheduler and passing an ID as parameter which distinguishes on job from another.

The process flow for scheduling a job in  [Quartz Tutorials(Cron)](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html) is given like below

Scheduler-->Job to Execute.

And to schedule multiple jobs, you have to create multiple JobDetail and Trigger Objects in Scheduler like the solution given in many Tutorials.

For example Scheduler(Trig1,Trig2)-->Job to Execute(Trig1,Trig2) if you have two jobs to schedule.

To schedule multiple jobs, I have built a layer before scheduler. And now my process flow is like this

MY Scheduler(parameters)-->Scheduler(parameters)-->Job to Execute(parameters)

Passing unique id in parameters is very important as each job should have a unique identity.